Draw straight-line diagram or single-line graph using Highcharts
I would like to use Highcharts (or similar) to display road attribute data as a straight-line diagram or single-line graph, but I can't find any examples that would be easy for this non-programmer to adapt. Is it possible to display linear referenced data on a single line using multiple colors using openly available chart-making software?
What I would like to accomplish:

Ex. data that will be queried from a database by road id/(range of ids):



road_id
mp_start
mp_end
surftype
sidewalks




1
0
2
1
1


1
2
4
1
1


1
4
5
2
1


1
5
10
3
0



An example I have found which gives me hope this is possible:
How to draw single-line graph, using highcharts
Additional wants: I would like to show multiple attributes like: surface type, sidewalks present, shoulder type etc. This would require multiple lines/color legends for each attribute for a given road id on the same page/graph/chart/frame with all lines sharing the same x-axis. It would be ideal if these lines could pan and zoom in-sync.

You can create such a chart using bar series in Highcharts library. When you set stacking option to normal each point should be a separate series. Moreover you can use some additional Highcharts options to adjust the chart to your preferable look.
API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.stacking
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tv9j65n4/
series: [{
 name: 'UNPAVED',
 data: [5]
}, {
 name: 'CONCRETE',
 data: [1]
}, {
 name: 'BITUMINOUS',
 data: [4]
}]

